# The value entered in the default value field of attribute is not getting displayed

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I created a new attribute with `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` as `Text Area`. Then I entered some code in the `default value` field. Now While creating a new product the filed of the attribute I created is empty instead of displaying the code which I have entered in the `default value` field.

The code which I have inserted is this,

```
<div class="brand-name">
<span><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ecompf16.png"}}" /></span>
<span><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ecompf26.png"}}" /></span>
</div>
```

Should I do anything additionally? Someone guide me please.

Comment: Which code you have inserted post in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Default Value` setting for product attribute will NOT set default value for already existing products. If you add new product, you can see that default value shown there for particular attribute.

Now you should use `Update attributes` action for updating multiple products from product grid from admin. And set that default value for this attribute and SAVE

[image]

Also Enable WYSIWYG for MultiMedia features on TextArea attribute

[image]

Comment: Yes You are correct.am not able to see the default value in already created products. But for new products am able to see it. thank you.

Comment: What should be done to display it for already created products?

Comment: Check Updated Answer